# Center and abelianization of a finite p-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

When working on a problem on characters of finite groups, I encounter the following. At the moment I don't have a good idea to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Let $P$ be a $p$-group, where $p$ is a prime. Is there any relation between $\exp(Z(P))$ and $\exp(P/P')$, where $\exp$ is the exponent, $Z(P)$ is the center, and $P'$ is the commutator subgroup? Is it true that $\exp(P/P')\leq \exp(Z(P))$, or even that $\exp(P/P')= \exp(Z(P))$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: While the answer proves that there is no connection, it *is* true that the exponents of the successive quotients in the lower central series do divide the exponent of $P/P'$. It is just that the last term of the LCS can be a proper subgroup of the centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have equality, or you can have either inequality.

1. For $\exp(P/P')=\exp(Z(P))$: take your favorite $p$-group $Q$, of order $p^n$. Let $C_{p^m}$ be a cyclic group of order $p^m$, with $m\gt n$. Then $P=Q\times C_{p^m}$ has center of exponent $p^m$, and abelianization isomorphic to $(P/P')\times C_{p^m}$, which has exponent $p^m$ as well. Alternatively, any nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$ (for $p$ odd), or $D_8$ or $Q_8$ for $p=2$.
2. For $\exp(P/P')\gt \exp(Z(P))$: let $p$ be an odd prime. Consider the set of all matrices of the form
   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & \alpha & \gamma\\
   0 & 1 & \beta\\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{array}\right)$$
   where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are taken in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, and $\gamma$ is taken in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, with $1\leq k\lt n$. Multiplication is then given by
   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & a & c\\
   0 & 1 & b\\
   0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & r & t\\
   0 & 1 & s\\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & a+r & c+t+a s\\
   0 & 1 & b+s\\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{array}\right).$$
   It is easy to verify that the abelianization is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, hence is of exponent $p^n$. The center consists of the matrices in which both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multiples of $p^k$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-k}\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}p^{n-k}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$. This has exponent $p^{\max(n-k,k)}$. Since $1\leq k\lt n$, then this is strictly smaller than $p^n=\exp(P/P')$.
3. For $\exp(P/P')\lt \exp(Z(P))$, let $p$ be an odd prime, and
   $$\begin{align*}
   Q &= \langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^p=1,\ xz=zx,\ yz=zy,\ yx=xyz\rangle\\
   R &= \langle w\mid w^{p^2}=1\rangle\\
   P &= (Q\times R)/\langle (z,w^{-p})\rangle.
   \end{align*}$$
   So $Q$ is the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, $R$ is cyclic of order $p^2$, and $P$ is the group obtained from $Q$ by adjoining a central $p$th root to $z$; call this root $r$ (that is, $r$ is the image of $(1,w)$ in the quotient). The center of $P$ is generated by $r$, hence has exponent $p^2$; the commutator subgroup of $P$ is generated by the image of $z$, so the abelianization is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, of exponent $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!